# img src variable not displaying pictures

Tags: php, html, variables

I have a list of image files inside mrtg/images directory. Files names are like:

```
router-day.png
router-week.png
switch-day.png
```

What I am trying to do is display image popup based on $hostname but it is not displaying any images;

```
 $hostname = router;
<img src="mrtg/images/<? echo $hostname;?>-day.png">
```

This is not working. If I put manually the filename then image is displayed.

```
 <img src="mrtg/images/router-day.png">
```

Any suggestion why it is not displaying images?

thank you

Comment: Can you update it with the EXACT php code you are using for testing purposes? in the example

`$hostname = router;
<img src="mrtg/images/<? echo $hostname;?>-day.png">`

You are mixing PHP and HTML.

Comment: The code displayed has many errors and is not relevant to the actual solution found.

Answer (score 2):

As someone told you, this will never work:

```
$hostname = router;
<img src="mrtg/images/<? echo $hostname;?>-day.png">
```

Two problemes there:

1 - The variable you are using, $hostname, isn't correctly assigned.
2 - You are mixing HTML and PHP.

The correct code should look more like this:

```
<?php
$hostname = 'router';
?>
<img src="mrtg/images/<? echo $hostname; ?>-day.png">
```

But this could be because you didn't provide an EXACT example of your code. If not, please do it.

Also I would encourage you to do this:

```
<img src="mrtg/images/<?php echo $hostname; ?>-day.png">
```

Or this:

```
<img src="mrtg/images/<?=$hostname?>-day.png">
```

Comment: Yes, the variable was not correctly assigned, It was assigned in upper case like ROUTER-day.png which result in image not being displayed. After adding strtolower function image got displayed. <img src="<? echo strtolower($hostname);?>\-day.png">

Comment: Also, if possible, try to use one of the last statements I've written.